# Getting Called From Wrong Thread Exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have activity which creates Thread to communicate with server. This thread every few seconds receives a String. I would like to add this String to list and display in activity (in ListView) but I'm getting CalledFromWrongThreadException when trying to do that.

```
class MyActivity() extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public MyActivity(){

        ...

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_element, list);

        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(true){
                        String dataFromServer = networkManager.receiveData();
                        list.add(dataFromServer);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I can not update main (UI) thread inside a worker thread. u can use asycktask and update UI onPostExecute() method of asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch back to the UI thread before you manipulate the list.

```
      list.post (new Runnable()
      {
        @Override public void run() 
        {
          String dataFromServer = networkManager.receiveData();
          list.add(dataFromServer);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use asynchronous operation in the UI thread I'd recommend you to use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Just wrap your thread execution in a class that extends AsyncTask.